# How to create banded columns in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

How do you create banded columns in Cognos Report Studio?

Here is an example of banded columns taken from this [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument16143):

[image]

EDIT:

Maybe this search string will help find this page?

"Cognos Report Studio, how to create column band"

Comment: Are you using a list or crosstab? You can do this in both but the procedure differs depending on the data container.

Comment: @Johnsonium I am just dropping fields on the report so I think it is a List but I am not sure... Maybe I should specifically put a List on the report?

Comment: @Johnsonium I confirmed that I am using a list and that a list is what is automatically created when you drop fields onto an empty spot on the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the procedure for a list:

1. Select the list object
2. In the *Structure* menu, select *Headers & Footers* and then *List Headers & Footers*
3. Check the box next to *List Page Header* and click OK
4. In the List object properties set the Column Titles property to *At start of details*
5. Select the new header
6. In the *Structure* menu, select *Headers & Footers* and then *Insert List Row Cells Above...*
7. Enter the number of header rows you want above the standard detail header and click OK
8. Delete the *List Page Header* row with 1 cell that was created in step 3
9. Select multiple horizontally-adjacent cells that you want to merge into one
10. In the *Structure* menu, select *Headers & Footers* and then *Merge List Row Cells*

Add some styling to the new header rows and end up with something like this:

[image]

Note that I couldn't vertically merge cells to produce the tall 'Sales Person' header in your mock-up. There may be a way to do this but that goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks! I am not done with the CSS but it seems to work so far.